# JQuery Datepicker selecting year

Tags: jquery

I wish for the user to be able to select the year without having to click on the prev or next tab relating to months. How can I accomplish this. Here is my code so far:

```
if ( $('[type="date"]').prop('type') != 'date' ) {
    $('[type="date"]').datepicker({
    //Something here

});
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is my configuration of datepiker I use font awesome icon so just igonore that.  what you want is the changeyear param.

```
$('#elementID').datepicker({ 
    showOn: 'both',
    buttonText: "<i class='fa fa-calendar fa-lg blue'></i>",
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true
});
```

Comment: This is perfect but why are the selects for the month and year so wide?

Comment: it seems that they take up the full row.  you can do an f12 and find out their css classes then try to override the width property.  the year class appears to be ui-datepicker-year.  It's up to you to decide if the return is worth the investment on that one. Good luck!